# How to use EXTERN in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, masm, extern, dosbox

These are my two programs:

#### atoi.asm

```
.model small

.data
ten dw  000ah
.code
atoi PROC
    mov si, 2[bp]
    xor cx, cx
    mov cl, [si]
    xor bx, bx
atoiloop1:
    inc si
    ;;more code
    ;;
returnfromatoi:
    xchg    ax, bx
    mov 4[bp],  ax
    ret
atoi ENDP

end
```

#### main.asm

```
.model small
EXTERN atoi 
.stack 100h
.data
;; data part
include c:\mylib.lby


.code
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    ;;somecode
    mov bp, sp
    call    atoi
    ;; somecode
    call    atoi
    ;; somecode
    jl  yes
    writestr    nomessage
    exit    00h
    yes:
    writestr    yesmessage
    exit    00h

main ENDP
end main
```

I want to compile and run in `dosbox`.

However, when I compile with `MASM.EXE MAIN.ASM`

It says `error: Expected: instruction or directive`.
I thought `extern` was a directive.

I thought this would compile and then I can do `LINK.EXE MAIN.o ATOI.o` or am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: Is that the line causing the error though? What version of masm?

Comment: yes the extern line is showing error. I can't copy the message from dosbox so i have typed it out. MASM version: **5.00**

Comment: Use `extrn atoi:proc` (note the spelling is missing an "e").

Comment: now I have another problem. when I do `LINK ATOI.OBJ MAIN.OBJ`, it says unresolved externals. Edit: I resolved my problem by adding a `public atoi` in atoi.asm

Comment: BTW, @Jester, using `extrn` solved that problem.